# how to get the next row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query in which data is coming from a table and in data there is no row of Sunday and i want to add the row of sunday using query .here is my query results and query

```
select bpv_date from all_dates
```

and the result is like this

```
01-dec-2012
02-dec-2012
03-dec-2012
04-dec-2012
05-dec-2012
06-dec-2012
.
.
.
.
30-dec-2012
```

I want to create dynamically a row of sunday for each month.Please Help !

Comment: What do you mean by "row of Sunday"? 02-dec-2012 and 30-dec-2012 are Sundays by the way.

Comment: what is the table structure? are there more columns or is that the only one, and whats its data type? (DATE or VARCHAR) ?

Comment: Actualy I have given example data i meant there is no data of the day of sunday and i want to add the row of sunday with blank data using sql query

Comment: So the 'missing' dates are in your `all_dates` look-up table, but you don't have any matching real data for those dates? That would suggest you just need an [outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55317), or possibly a union. You need to show your current query to see what modification it needs.

Comment: Sir kindly Tell me Is ther any way that if query find `SAT` in row then it shows 'SUN' in next row

Comment: @user1915635 So you are working with strings and not dates?  do your rows just say 'MON' 'TUE' 'WED' etc... or are they like you posted in your OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My penny (something like joke:))

```
select bpv_date
from all_dates
union
select bpv_date + 1 
from all_dates
where to_char(bpv_date, 'D') = 7  -- saturday for NLS_LANG='AMERICAN', otherwise use 6
```

Comment: It's tough when the requirements are hazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can do this :  `to_char(sysdate,'DY')` to figure out which day is sunday, then add it to an `if` statement, then loop, like this :

```
 BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..365 LOOP
    IF( to_char(sysdate-1+i,'DY') IN ('SUN') )
    THEN
      INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, MY_DATE)
        VALUES (i, (to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')-1)+i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This will create a table that only has sundays in it.  I'm unsure wether this is what you want or not, but your question is rather vague.

Comment: Or `select sysdate + level from dual connect by level <= 365`